# calling class method in another class which intern used in the same class

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop

am trying to call the class method which is used again in the main class

```
from src.another_class import B
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    
    def one():
        a = 'doing something'
        if a :
            add, sub = B.do_something(x, y, z)
    
    def add(a, b):
        pass
    def sub(a, b):
        pass
```

#this will be in another folder called source

```
from A_class import A
class B:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    
    def do_something(x, y, z):
        
        add = A.two(x, y)
        
        sub = A.sub(x, z)
        return add, sub
```

is there a best way to do this. am new to python oops concepts.

Comment: What are `A.two` and `A.sub` supposed to do? I also feel like you're doing something unnecessary with the `B` class - why not make it an instance in A? Also, if you want to call the method like `B.do_something`, you have to make it either `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @EricJin Basically, in real, my class A is filled with so many methods, so i want to split few methods into classes for easy understanding.

Comment: Making those links between classes makes it more difficult to document/understand in my opinion. It’s best to give it a good name and leave it in the original class.